# A small planet with earthlike gravity

Tags: planets, gravity

Is it possible to create an Earthlike planet, that is smaller than the Earth , like for example the size of Mars, by altering the core composition like for example making it:

- Iron (Piron ): 75.6%
- Nickel (Pnickel ): 22.0%
- Other Heavy Materials (Pother ): 2.4%

Is it possible to have a planet with a gravity similar (but not equal) to Earth's gravity, with a similar atmosphere and biosphere as well?

My idea is to have a desert world, so if there are features that make that more likely, that's even better.

Comment: Isn't this what you posted before https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/254082/30492 as a closed question? You should edit that post and have it reopened, not repost it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Smaller planet Gravity and similarity to Earth one](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/254082/smaller-planet-gravity-and-similarity-to-earth-one)

Comment: How DO I open it ? Sorry but I thoguth now one wanted to answer so I thought to open a new one mostly concerning manipulation of core density.

Comment: The moment you say desert world, the same biosphere as earth is impossible.

Comment: @Naima - the answer to the previous question was pretty comprehensive.  What wasn't covered?

Comment: For that matter, "Desert Worlds" a la Tatooine and Arrakis are the domain of science fantasy, not science-based fiction.  A true desert world looks like Mars.  You need water in relative abundance to have a breathable atmosphere.

Answer (score -2):

The equation for surface gravity is  $F=\frac{G\times M1 \times M2}{D^2}$ (The gravitation constant G multiplied by the mass of object 1 multiplied by the mass of object 2. That is then divided by the square of the distance from the center of mass of object 1 to the center of mass of object 2).

You asked,

> Is it possible to have a planet with a gravity similar (but not equal) to Earth's gravity, with a similar atmospherr and biosphere as well?

Yes.

Since you guys want to be picky about it, if the smaller world had an extremely dense mass that was not at the geometric center of that world, and if that smaller world had a much less dense mountain geometrically opposite to that mass. Add a moon for adjusting the atmosphere. As long as it satisfied the equation, then that would work. It might have some extreme variation of surface gravity and surface conditions, but in at least part of it the conditions could match those of Earth. It might make for an interesting game world.

Comment: This is not true.  You can have a tiny planet with Earth's gravity but only a fraction of Earth's mass.  Surface gravity is a function of radius as well as mass.

Comment: @jdunlop, I missed that. f=gm1m2/r2. OK. I adjusted my answer for that.

Comment: Surface gravity isn't typically expressed as a force, but as an acceleration, since that holds constant for all objects on the surface of a body.  I also edited the answer to use mathjax so the formula is legible.

Comment: @jdunlop, thank you for the edit. I expect it to give you points. But your equation is wrong. It is not GxM. It is GxM1xM2. The gravitation constant G multiplied by the mass of object 1 multiplied by the mass of object 2. That is then divided by the square of the distance from the center of mass of object 1 to the center of mass of object 2. Since you guys want to be picky about it, if the smaller world had an extremely dense mass that was not at the geometric center of that world, and if that smaller world had a much less dense mountain geometrically opposite to that mass

Comment: and if the height of that mountain were sufficient to satisfy the equation that I gave, then with f=gm1m2/d2 would be sufficient to answer the question. The question did include, "by altering the core composition," and therefore I have answered the question with "Yes."

Comment: It appears to me that @jdunlop edited the right side of the equation, but forgot to change force to acceleration. Since, as they said before, surface gravity is usually expressed in terms of acceleration, not force, which *would* approximate GxM/r^2, assuming that M1 >>> M1 in the equation for the force (which is how it's usually stated, such as earth being ~9.8m/s^2)

Comment: Sorry, yes.  Should've changed the f to a.  Will do.

Comment: Also, @LineItem - you don't get points for edits, they are strictly a public service.